# webpack dev server not working

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a `webpack.config.js` file like this:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
        ]
    }
};
```

and my `package.json` is like:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register --recursive tests/*.js",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "build": "webpack --progress --profile --colors",
    "build:watch": "webpack --progress --profile --colors --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
```

but when I run `npm run start` it gives me error saying..

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

What is the issue here ??

Answer (score 1):

It could be a "port" issue when launching webpack dev server. try `webpack-dev-server --port 3000`